# My discord.js bot wont start when I run "npm run start"

Tags: javascript, package.json, npm-scripts

When I try and run npm run start in my console for my discord.js bot I have no idea why it won't work.

(here is my package.json)

```
{
  "name": "spinier-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Moderation & utility bot with a little bit of fun sprinkled in.",
  "main": "src/bot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/rest": "^1.2.0",
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.37.12",
    "discord.js": "^14.5.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3"
  }
}
```

I was looking for a solution for this and I could not find anything, I just want to know how I can fix it so I can get my bot online for testing. (I don't know much about discord.js or JavaScript at all so I have no idea what is going on).

Comment: `"start": "node ."`, not `"test": "node ."`

Comment: now I get this https://paste.ee/p/bBYzN#YspaB9Ex0r1smO7bXCx5GT28AUPjvWyE

Comment: Why would you run `npm start test`? Anyway, the last error is pretty straightforward. It can't find `discordSort.js`. I think it would be better for you to follow some online tutorials to build a bot. It's going to be pretty tough if you don't know JavaScript and Node.js though.

Comment: I am following a tutorial, but this command should start up the bot, and its not so I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```json
{
  "name": "spinier-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Moderation & utility bot with a little bit of fun sprinkled in.",
  "main": "src/bot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/rest": "^1.2.0",
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.37.12",
    "discord.js": "^14.5.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3"
  }
}
```

Here, I changed the `test` script to `start`.

Comment: I already tried that, but I get this other error  paste.ee/p/bBYzN#YspaB9Ex0r1smO7bXCx5GT28AUPjvWyE